# how to write a bash script that would get minor and major device numbers of /dev/random

Tags: linux, bash, mknod

I am trying to run a program in a chrooted environment, and it needs `/dev/random` as a resource.
Manually I can do `ls -l` on it and then create the file again with `mknod c xx yy`, but I need to make it automatic and I don't think these version numbers are constant from a linux version to another so that is why I have the following question :

How could I write a bash script that would extract the minor and major numbers of `/dev/random` and use it with mknod? I can use `ls -l` but I don't know how to extract a substring of it...

The exact return of `ls -l /dev/random` is :

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root MINOR, MAJOR mars  30 19:15 /dev/random
```

and the two numbers I want to extract are MINOR and MAJOR. However if there is an easier way to create the node without ls and mknod I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the major and minor device numbers with `stat`:

```
MINOR=`stat -c %T /dev/random`
MAJOR=`stat -c %t /dev/random`
```

You can then create a device node with:

```
mknod mydevice c "0x$MAJOR" "0x$MINOR"
```

Another approach (which doesn't require the parsing of device numbers) is to use `tar` to create an archive with the details of the device files in:

```
cd /dev
tar cf /somewhere/devicefiles.tar random null [any other needed devices]
```

then

```
cd /somewhere/chroot-location
tar xf /somewhere/devicefiles.tar
```

This latter method has the advantage that it doesn't rely on the `-c` option to `stat`, which is a GNU extension.

Comment: FYI, from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08 -- *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications.  Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: ...thus, the convention of using lower-case variable names inside scripts where possible is actually enshrined in POSIX.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Those comments refer to environment variables, right?

Comment: the tar command is very interesting since I wouldn't have to read /dev on the other machine, would it work if I would use ‘cp -a /dev/random‘ into my chrooted environment, tar this environment, and deploy it on a new machine? I am going to try that.

Comment: @psmears: Correct, but even changing a shell variable will impact the environment if any environment variable with the same name exists. Thus, if one wants to be certain of writing scripts that won't modify the system's behavior as an unintended side effect, the convention applies to all shell variables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It may be a good guideline to follow, but unfortunately you can't be "certain" of that even if you do follow the convention; eg the "http_proxy" (lower case) environment variable affects the behaviour of a number of programs. It might work if (a) you stick 100% to POSIX-specified utilities, and (b) your system is 100% POSIX compliant, but that would be an unusual situation, in my experience ;-)

Comment: @psmears, sadly, yes, there are exceptions -- that doesn't mean that following the rule is no longer best practice. If I had a dollar for every time I saw someone write `for PATH in $PATHS; do`, it would at least pay for lunch. :)

Comment: Mhm. Probably you should use `%Hr` and `%Hd` instead. `stat` and `%T, %t` do provide hexadecimal result which is not prefixed by `0x` and that is expected by `mknod`.

Comment: Argh. Apparently it's `%Hr` and `%Lr` for decimal major/minor for character devices.

Comment: @Kamiccolo: Good catch on the output being in hex! Probably easiest just to supply the required `0x` to `mknod`; have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @psmears heh, apparently it's a better choice for some more reasons: `%Hr` and `%Lr` is not a thing on older GNU coreutils. For example <= 8.30

Comment: @Kamiccolo: OK - that's actually a pretty recent addition, at least in terms of making it to all the LTS versions of major distros...

Answer (score 4):

A minor improvement to efficiency would be to do only one call (and to use lower-case variable names, as is conventional for all variables other than builtins and environment variables in shell):

```
read minor major < <(stat -c '%T %t' /dev/random)
```

---

On a GNU system, by the way, I'd suggest using `cp -a` to copy your explicitly whitelisted device files into the chroot during setup:

```
cp -a /dev/random /your/chroot/dev/random
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

MAJOR=`ls -l /dev/random  | awk '{ print $5}'`

MINOR=`ls -l /dev/random  | awk '{ print $6}'`

Comment: Not safe -- see the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html -- "If the file is a character special or block special file, the size of the file may be replaced with **implementation-defined** information associated with the device in question." (emphasis added). Thus, there's no guarantee that any given version of `ls` will use a particular format for output when listing device nodes.

Comment: I did not know about awk which seems pretty interesting but the other solutions seem a lot better indeed.

Comment: Granted, the `stat` behavior in question isn't POSIX-defined either -- but using `-c` on a non-GNU `stat` is likely to give an outright error, whereas parsing a non-GNU `ls` can result in a silently wrong answer.